# Issue with sum(case when ... ) with multiple condition

Tags: sql

Quick one. I would like to place multiple condition in a case when command.

Here is what I would like to achieve:

```
sum(case when "Ticket Number" LIKE 'INC%' AND "Support Person" = null  then 1 else 0 end) 'INC N/A'
```

The AND is not working. What would be the right syntax?

Thanks,

Comment: try IS NULL instead of = NULL

Comment: and why do you use quotes for column names?

Comment: Unrelated to your actual problem, but it doesn't look like you're actually trying to sum. Just adding 1 each time is counting which is more naturally done with the `count` function. `count(case when ... then 1 end)` without any `else` should work as soon as you get the condition right.

Comment: @vkp That's the standard syntax. Backticks and square brackets are extensions in some dialects of SQL, but the ANSI quoting syntax (widely supported) uses double quotes.

Comment: I use the Quotes because of the spaces in the column name.

Comment: HEre is the new line: Count(case when "Ticket Number" LIKE 'INC%' AND "Support Person" IS NULL then 1 END) 'INC N/A' . Do I keep the then 1?

Comment: @Rimo72 `count` simply checks how many non-`NULL` values you have. `case when <condition> then <value> end` evaluates to `<value>` when `<condition>` is true, or `NULL` otherwise. So the actual value is ignored. `1`, `'hello'` or `0.123456789` would all have the same effect with `count`. `1` and `0` are two common values that are used for that.

Comment: @vkp: because spaces (or other special characters) are not allowed in an unquoted identifier. To use a column name like `Ticket Number` you *have* to use quotes in SQL which also makes the column name case sensitive. `"Ticket Number"` and `"TICKET NUMBER"` are different identifiers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IS NULL` instead of `= null`:

```
when "Ticket Number" LIKE 'INC%' AND "Support Person" IS NULL
```

Comment: HEre is the new line: Count(case when "Ticket Number" LIKE 'INC%' AND "Support Person" IS NULL then 1 END) 'INC N/A' . Do I keep the then 1?

Comment: @Rimo72 . . . My vote is for the `sum()` in your question rather than `count()`.  In this context, I find it confusing that `count(0)`, `count(1)`, and `count(2)` all do the same thing.  I think `sum()` is much clearer.